# How to create a json object with hierarchical object and values?

Tags: c++, json, c++11, casablanca

How to create a hierarchical JSON object and value structure using Casablanca/cpprestsdk JSON library?

I referred to the following links. But I could not figure out placing the JSON object in another JSON object

https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/JSON
https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/namespaceweb_1_1json.html

## JSON Object:

```
{
    "employee" :
    {
        "name" : "vinkris",
        "age"  : "30"
    }
}

{
    struct employee emp;
    string object = U("{") + U("employee:") + U("{") ;
    object += U("name:") + emp.name + U(",") ;
    object += U("age:") + std::to_string(emp.age) + U("}") ;
    json::value = json::value::string(object)
}
```

Is there any to simplify how the JSON body can be constructed?

For example:

```
{
    JsonObject object();
    JsonSubObjects subObject();
    subObjects.add("name", "vinkris");
    subObjects.add("age", "30");
    object.add("employee", subObject)
}
```

I am very new to both [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and Casablanca library. Wondering if this is possible?

It would be great to get some pointers on how to build something like this.

Answer (score 0):

this

```
json::value obj      = json::value::object();
json::value employee = json::value::object();

employee[U("name")]  = json::value::string(U("vinkris"));
employee[U("age")]   = json::value::number(30);

obj[U("employee")]   = employee;
```

turns to this:

`{"employee":{"age":30,"name":"vinkris"}}`